# sql query to get multiple data through date

Tags: sql, sql-server

table ta having four columns ( SQL server and D column is date)

```
A | B | C|D
1 |11| 0|10-MAY-2019
1 |12| 0|10-MAY-2019
1 |13| 0|null
2 |33| 5|null
2 |34| 10|null
2 |35| 78|null
5 |45| 0|10-MAY-2019
5 |49| 0|10-MAY-2019
5 |51| 0|10-MAY-2019
8 |10| 0|1-MAY-2018
8 |14| 0|1-MAY-2018
8 |34| 0|1-MAY-2018
```

I am looking the SQL query to fetch the distinct A value which is having C value ZERO for all the B (ie. SUM(ABS(C))=0)  and all D value for that will not be null and should be > GETDATE() - 90 (i.e any day between current date and 90 days)

From above table I would only get the value of A as '5'

Comment: what would your expected result look like?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? `GETDATE()` is a SQL Server function. Different databases have different functions. You should also post the table schema. If the `D` column is a `varchar` instead of a `date` filtering and grouping become a lot harder, especially when the text format can't be sorted chronologically

Comment: @Panagiotis SQL server and D is the Date

Comment: @asinha update the question and include enough information to allow people to help you. Post the table schema, the `INSERT` statement and the desired results.

Comment: @Adnan I need the distinct A value which would be only 5

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT A  
    FROM your_table
    WHERE D > CAST(DATEADD(DD,-90,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    GROUP BY A
    HAVING COUNT(A) = SUM(CASE WHEN C= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM your_table B WHERE A.A = B.A
    AND D IS NULL
)
```

Comment: it does not work.[Code: 156, SQL State: S1000]  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.. However if I change that to  D > GETDATE() - 90 then the result though comes but it does not have each value of B is ZERO.

Comment: I have add NOT EXISTS option so than only 5 returns as output.

Comment: This will work now. Please check again as there were a ) missing before AS and also ALL C= 0 is considered now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  I think this is the logic you describe:

```
select a
from t
where d > dateadd(day, -90, getdate()) or d is null
group by a
having max(c) = 0 and
       count(*) = count(d);  -- no NULL d values
```